# Is there is way to embed UIView's in UIScrollview without losing subviews constraints in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have too many subviews in my ContentView and now I want this contentView in UIScrollview but if I do that I lose all the subview's constraints. Editor->Embed in UIScrollview is not working.

Is there any way to embed ContentView in UIScrollView ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select your controls now go on Editor->EmbedIn->View

Comment: This will remove subviews constraints.

Comment: Yes you have to again apply constraints but frames not change which will consume your time.

Answer (score 2):

Not reliable answer. but fixed by selecting ContentView

Editor->Embed in -> Scroll View

Then Xcode complaining constraints. Clicked on Red button and just selected "Add missing constraints". this fixed for me.

Comment: I think this is the best way to start. Works for most view.

Comment: @Avijit Nagare You saved my life, bro

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a little tricky, so make sure to have a backup of your storyboard/xib, but if you use 'Open as' > 'Source Code' (control click on the file) and find the view in the XML and change both the opening and closing tag from `view` to `scrollView`. Now when you do 'Open as' > 'Interface Builder' you got yourself a scroll view instead.

Please note that constraints to the top and bottom of the view default to use the top and bottom layout guides, but if you want it to scroll you need to use top or bottom space to the container view (the scroll view). You can do that by pressing option when creating the constraints.